# Why appending list to itself, and then deleting, results in memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I found this [memory leak detection snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65333/) and was wondering about the memory leak it generated.

```
import gc

def dump_garbage():
    """
    show us what's the garbage about
    """

    # force collection
    print("\nGARBAGE:")
    gc.collect()

    print("\nGARBAGE OBJECTS:")
    for x in gc.garbage:
        s = str(x)
        if len(s) > 80: s = s[:80]
        print(type(x),"\n  ", s)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import gc
    gc.enable()
    gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)

    # make a leak
    l = []
    l.append(l)
    del l

    # show the dirt ;-)
    dump_garbage()
```

In order to test the gc memory leak detection, the author created its own little mem leak:

```
l = []
l.append(l)
del(l)
```

Why would that result in a leak? As I see it, I would have a list object, and than a nested list object, where the inner *is* the outer, and than delete the outer. Wouldn't the gc know to delete all references to the original list and thus result in a leaked inner list?

Comment: The article is from 2001. Python 1.x relied solely on reference counting for GC, and cyclic references are the textbook example for when that fails. Python 2 introduced a cycle-detection step, which should cope with this case. There were some remaining wrinkles such as presence of a `__del__` method preventing GC, but I believe they, too, have been ironed out in later versions of Python 3.

Comment: garbage still shown with python 3.x so no...

Comment: The snippet in the question sets GC_DEBUG_LEAK, which implies GC_DEBUG_SAVEALL, which means that "all unreachable objects will be appended to garbage rather than freed". If I run `python3 -c 'for k in range(1000000000): l = [k]; l.append(l)`, the process never grows much bigger than about 7 Mbyte, despite having allocated millions of circular lists.

Comment: @TurePålsson I've deleted my answer which is wrong. But you could make an answer with your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Editing my earlier comments into an answer.)

The linked article is from 2001. Back in those days, Python 2.x was new, and many people were probably still using Python 1.x.

Python 1.x relied solely on reference counting for garbage collection, and cyclic references are the textbook example of when that fails. Python 2.x added a cycle detection step, but there were some remaining wrinkles, such as the presence of a `__del__` method blocking the garbage collector, because it could not figure out the proper order of destruction. As of Python 3.4, [most of the wrinkles have been ironed out](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage).

So why does the example code still indicate leaks? It sets the [`GC_DEBUG_LEAK`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.DEBUG_LEAK) flag which, among other things, explicitly tells the garbage collector to keep unreachable objects around!

Comment: So, in py3. 4+, without setting this flag, the gc will know to collect this list and free it?

Comment: Yes. (I have to write something more here to make the comment long enough.)

Answer (score -5):

Most likely it's quite similar to an infinite loop:
While `l = []` and `l.append(l)` the compiler has problems identifying if the list is `[]` or `[[]]` or `[[[]]]` because the list is appended to itself.

I hope you understand it, you can see my shell example here:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(l)
>>> l
[[...]]

#Then, again:

>>> l = []
>>> l.append(l)
>>> l.append(l)
>>> l

[[...], [...]]

>>> l[0], l[1]

([[...], [...]], [[...], [...]])

>>> l[0][0]

[[...], [...]]

>>> l[0][0][0]

[[...], [...]]    # and so on...
```

So, you can see `l` is basically and infinite list, and deleting an infinte list would end in a memory leak (I don't know the reason but you can dig deeper if you want to...)

Hope this helped.

**EDIT**:
The shell truly outputs the text `[...]`, just in case if you were wondering.